# Is there anything I can do about the overhead from running a shader multiple times

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I'm trying to implement deferred rendering on an Android phone using OPENGL ES 3.0. I've gotten this to work ok but only very slowly, which rather defeats the whole point. What really slows things up is the multiple calls to the shaders. Here, briefly, is what my code does:

1. Geometry Pass:

   Render scene - output position, normal and colour to off-screen buffers.
2. For each light:

   a) Stencil Pass:

   Render a sphere at the current light position, sized according to the lights intensity. Mark these pixels as influenced by current light. No actual output.

   b) Light Pass:

   Render a sphere again, this time using the data from the geometry pass to apply lighting equations to pixels marked in the previous step. Add this to off-screen buffer
3. Blit to screen

It's this restarting the shaders for each light causing the bottleneck. For example, with 25 lights the above steps run at about 5 fps. If instead I do: Geometry Pass / Stencil Pass - draw 25 lights / Light Pass - draw 25 lights it runs at around 30 fps. So, does anybody know how I can avoid having to re-initialize the shaders? Or, in fact, just explain what's taking up the time? Would it help or even be possible (and I'm sorry if this sounds daft) to keep the shader 'open' and overwrite the previous data rather than doing whatever it is that takes so much time restarting the shader? Or should I give this up as a method for having  multiple lights, on a mobile devise anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem of having to swap shaders for each light by using an integer texture as a stencil map, where a certain bit is set to represent each light. (So, limited to 32 lights.) This means step 2a (above) can be looped, then a single change of shader, and looping step 2b. However, (ahahaha!) it turns out that this didn't really speed things up as it's not, after all, swapping shaders that's the problem but changing write destination. That is, multiple calls to `glDrawBuffers`. As I had two such calls in the stencil creation loop - one to draw nowhere when drawing a sphere to calculate which pixels are influenced and one to draw to the integer texture used as the stencil map. I finally realized that as I use blending (each write with a colour where a singe bit is on) it doesn't matter if I write at the pixel calculation stage, so long as it's with all zeros.  Getting rid of the unnecessary calls to `glDrawBuffers` takes the FPS from single figures to the high twenties.

In summary, this method of deferred rendering is certainly faster than forward rendering but limited to 32 lights.

I'd like to say that me code was written just to see if this was a viable method and many small optimizations could be made. Incidentally, as I was limited to 4 draw buffers, I had to scratch the position map and instead recover this from `gl_FragCoord.xyz`. I don't have proper benchmarking tools so I'd be interested to hear from anyone who can tell me what difference this makes, speedwise.